# How do I remove a certain data in R? (multiple regression)

Tags: r

I implemented multiple regressions on babies data (UsingR).
I set the birth weight (wt) as dependent variable, and others as independent variables.
And when I print it with summary it showed me that gestation is not significant as much as race, ht(mon's height).
So I printed the relation(Scatterplot), and it showed me that there are some "unknown value which are something like 99, or 999"
According to the babies data (UsingR), it sets the unknown data as 99 or 999 value.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/UsingR/UsingR.pdf
What I am trying to do is to get rid of 99 and 999 values and show the scatterplot and multiple regressions.
Any idea?

```
install.packages("UsingR")
library(UsingR)
head(babies)

m <- lm(wt ~ gestation + ht + wt1 + dht + dwt, data=babies)
summary(m)
anova(m)

plot(babies$wt,babies$ht) #mon's height
plot(babies$wt,babies$dwt) #dad's weight
```

Comment: You could use a subset (as in the example in the documentation) to remove unknown values.

Comment: can you explain to me more specifically? I did not get it.
for example
m <- lm(wt ~ gestation < 300 , data=babies)
with above regressions it will work, but 
m <- lm(wt ~ gestation < 300 + race < 10 , data=babies)
When I have multiple independent variables it does not work.
How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are certain that the unknown data as 99 or 999 value, then you can set all 99 or 999 values to NA

```
  babies[babies == 99] <- NA
  babies[babies == 999] <- NA
```

and then run your scripts

You should ideally go to page 10 of the pdf and look at the codes for unknown and set them variable wise to NA based on how the unknown is set. For example :

```
 babies$wt[babies$wt == 99] <- NA
```

Comment: If you do this you will loose real values. For example in `wt1` variable there are real 99 values ... There is probably no other way than to do it variable by variable by checking in the dataset help how are coded the missing values. For example `inc` has both 98 and 99 (slightly different) missing values

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you want to do is replace the values that are 99 and 999 with `NA` values, right? Most of the modeling functions in R know how to handle `NA` values and will ignore them, or at least have tools in them for you to say how to handle them.

Here is one way for you to replace all those values with `NA`, using `mutate_if()` from dplyr and `ifelse()`:

```r
library(UsingR)
library(dplyr)

data(babies)
mean(babies == 99 | babies == 999)
#> [1] 0.03869425

babies_processed <- babies %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(ifelse(. == 99 | . == 999, NA, .)))

mean(babies_processed == 99 | babies_processed == 999, na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] 0
```